# Playwright cannot find project from the config file

Tags: playwright

I am trying to do some e2e testing on playwright. I'm trying to check my react app on an iPhone 13 on a safari and when I run this command :
`npx playwright test --headed --browser=webkit --project=Mobile Safari`

I get the following error :
Error: Project(s) "Mobile" not found. Available named projects: "webkit"

I have set up my playwright.config.ts this way just like the first example given here : https://playwright.dev/docs/emulation

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rename your project to something like `MobileSafari` and try again?

Comment: --project="Mobile Safari" or --project='Mobile Safari'